# Oozie in CDH5 does not pick up mapreduce.job.counters.max

Tags: hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh

When I run an oozie workflow which runs a mapreduce-action that creates more than 120 counters (120 is the default maximum number of counters allowed), I get an error saying "Too many counters".

I have set mapreduce.job.counters.max to a higher number than 120, but oozie does not seem to pick this up.

I am using hadoop 2.3 on CDH 5.1

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to be to add the following to *YARN Service MapReduce Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve)*:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.counters.max</name>
    <value>SOMENUMBER</value>
</property>
```